# Interpreting Sequences and their set Notation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am using Ross: Elementary Analysis 2nd Edition.

I do not know how to interpret sets of this type:

*" If $L=\limsup s_n \neq \infty$ then for every $\alpha >L$ the set $\{n: s_n > \alpha \}$ is finite."*

Generally, how do you interpret sets like 
$\{n: s_n > \alpha \}$?

Does this set include as its the element every index, $n$, of every term in the sequence $(s_n)$ greater than $\alpha$? i.e. The elements of the set will just be natural numbers...?

Comment: Yes. It actually means $\{n\in N:s_n>\alpha\}$, where $N$ is the set that the sequence indexed (most likely $\mathbb N$, sometimes $\mathbb Z$)

Comment: Yes.  It is a set of indexes.  Precisely the indexes, k for all the k where $s_k > \alpha$.  The fact that it is a set isn't that important.  It's really just a way to reference the $s_k$ where $s_k > \alpha$ directly by their index number.

Comment: Ah so the way the set is being used is to just make the statement that there are finitely many terms of $s_{n}$ that are greater than $\alpha$?